# convert an undirected graph in CSV format to RDF format using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, graph-databases

I have a CSV format file that stores a Graph. It contains two columns source vertex id and destination vertex id. Ids are integers in a range [0,max_vertex-1]. I want to convert it into an RDF format file. I know that we can do it using a SPARQL query utilizing the "CONSTRUCT" phrase.
But not completely sure how to write my query since I don't have subject, predicate, and object here.
If all the edges are of equal weight or no weight, just a simple undirected graph, does SPARQL help in writing a query to convert the CSV file to RDF format.

If such a query exists, can someone help me with the SPARQL query? I don't know much of SPARQL.

Comment: SPARQL is a query language for RDF data, you have to first load the CSV into the triple store which means you would have to convert it to RDF in advance. What you want and need is R2RML or in your case RML mappings

Comment: Alternatively, I suggest to use [SPARQL generate](https://ci.mines-stetienne.fr/sparql-generate/) or [SPARQL integrate](https://github.com/SmartDataAnalytics/RdfProcessingToolkit/blob/develop/README-SI.md), both being tools capable of converting CSV ot RDF via extended SPARQL syntax

Comment: by the way, any Python or whatever script would need no SPARQL at all, just process this simple CSV file line by line and create a simple line for the RDF triple

Comment: Thank You @UninformedUser Your comments helped me. Now I know how to create an RDF file from a CSV file without using SPARQL.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're trying to develop is the intermediate layer between your data (the csv file) and a graph (which you can then run SPARQL queries on). The intermediate layer that you're after is often called *triplification*, which is the process of turning raw data into RDF triples.

One common way to do this is with Python's rdflib. As a sketch, you should load your csv into python and loop over each row, constructing the appropriate triple at each iteration and add it to the graph.

An immediate problem that you mention is you don't have any predicates-which is an absolute requirement for the RDF data model (it's how you connect nodes). I would suggest finding an ontology with an appropriate term and use it to connect the nodes, or make up your own term as I've done below if you're exploring the data.

Some pseudocode...

```
import rdflib

# Create the graph object which holds the triples
graph = rdflib.Graph()

For each row in csv file:
   s = rdflib.URIRef(f'#/{row["column_1]}')
   p = rdflib.URIRef("#connectsTo")
   o = rdflib.URIRef(f'#/{row["column_2"]}')
   graph.add((s, p, o))

g.serialize(destination='graph.ttl', format='turtle')
```

From here, you can load `graph.ttl` into a graph store that supports RDF or run a separate reasoner over it.

To avoid any confusion with SPARQL-it's used to query *existing* graphs; the CONSTRUCT query takes an existing graph and returns a new graph.

Comment: if the graph is in a ".ttl" file then what are ".nq" or ".nt" files. Are graphs coded in RDF format in ".nt" or ".nq" files? Can Python rdflib help in creating those files?

Comment: Glad to help-be sure to accept the answer if it worked. There are many different ways to represent Graphs/RDF, we refer to these as 'serialization formats'. A '.ttl' file is RDF serialized in the Turtle Terse format, '.nq' is RDF serialized as N-Quads, and 'nt' is RDF serialized as N-Triples (google those terms for more info).
RDFLib supports all of these formats. In g.serialize() set the format equal to “xml”, “n3”, “turtle”, “nt”, “pretty-xml”, “trix”, “trig” or “nquads” for your desired format.

Comment: Thank You. I guessed this answer looking at the code.

Comment: The code worked. Except that the last line must be "graph.serialize()" and not "g.serialize" since you started with graph= rdflib.graph()